# How do you pull data from a database to another one using a linked server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I have a local server set up on my computer with a local database. I am trying to connect to a network server with a linked server (I'm having a lot of trouble with this) and then create tables and views in the local database from the data in the network database. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

Comment: Is this just so you can develop on your local PC? Would just getting a backup of the database from the network server be easier?

Comment: @HardCode I'm actually just testing it this way to get it working. I'm going to be setting up a read only proxy with two servers on the network, but to test it I'm using a test server on the network and the local server on my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like :

```
SELECT * from openquery(LINKED_SERVER_NAME,'SELECT * FROM TABLE')
```

If your linked server is well configured, you should be able to query the tables in the linked server using [openquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms188427.aspx).

Comment: I'm not sure my linked server is well configured. I think it is connected to the right server, but I'm not sure it is connected to the right database on the server and I'm kind of lost on how to do that. I'm new to this task in particular.

Comment: @user2256498 you could read this tutorial on how to configure a linked server : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx

Comment: @user2256498 depending on how it is configured, you should be able to access the tables from the linked server. Have you tried your query with openquery ?

Comment: @user2256498 Glad I could help! If it solves you problem please consider upvoting and accepting the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. First you link the Server then run query against the linked Server.

```
EXEC Sp_addlinkedserver
  @server="MY-PC\SQLServer1",
  @srvproduct='SQL Server'

-- from SQL Server2 you run this query
SELECT *
FROM   Openquery("my-pc\sqlserver1", 'select * from Students')
```

Reference: [Running Query against linked Server](http://hammadk.com/running-query-against-linked-server/)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM [LINKEDSERVERNAME].[DATABASENAME].[DBO].[TABLENAME]
```